# How to convert date to 6 digits number?

Tags: datetime, format

Hi i have this date January, 04, 2001 I want to convert it to 6 digits
Like this example : March 28, 1998 TO 032898

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what platform you are using but if you are using excel spreadsheet than you could use something like this:

[image]

If 'DATA' is at A1 location then '6/6/2020' will be at A2 location.
So at B2 location you can use this formula: =TEXT(A2,"mmddyy")

Hope that Answers your question.

Comment: none platform, i just want it for my online uses